# R - creating a huge dimensional binary matrix

Tags: r

I have a data like following format:

```
1   21  32  95436   23  98  213 34
2   876 765 9   32  12  65  698076
3   543 76  9087    23  65  434 786
4   2   87  65  387 8976    43  87
....
```

The first column shows the row ID. I want to make a binary matrix in a way that each entry indicates the column name. For example, [1,21]=1, [1,32]=1,......
I am trying to find something in R to make my life easier.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We could use the `sparseMatrix` from `library(Matrix)`.

```
library(Matrix)
sP <-  sparseMatrix(df1[,1][row(df1[-1])], unlist(df1[-1]), x=1)
m1 <- as.matrix(sP)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(V1= 1:4, V2= sample(1:7, 4, 
               replace=FALSE), V3= 8:11)
```